# How to set baseUrl (also for apostrophe-multisite)

Tags: apostrophe-cms

I am working on an Apostrophe project using the multisite module, and since running an `npm update` the `_urls` for pages begin with `/baseUrl-not-set`. I can only find this as far as documentation:

> baseUrl (GLOBAL OPTION, NOT SET FOR THIS SPECIFIC MODULE)
>   As a convenience, req.absoluteUrl is set to the absolute URL of the current request. If the baseUrl option at the top level, not for this specific module is set to a string such as http:://mysite.com, any site-wide prefix and req.url are appended to that. Otherwise the absolute URL is constructed based on the browser's request. Setting the baseUrl global option is necessary for reasonable URLs when generating markup from a command line task.

[source](https://apostrophecms.org/docs/modules/apostrophe-express/index.html#code-base-url-code)

So, I'm not sure from there is a `baseUrl` property would be added to app.js (remember this is a multisite project, so it needs to be dynamic), or `apostrophe-globa/index.js` as a root-level property to the module, or under `addFields` (all of which I have tried, to no avail).

So basically since `npm updating`, my URL structure for all URLs is currently broken, and I can't do any deploys at the moment.

Would really appreciate some guidance here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry this went undocumented for a day, the instructions are now part of the module's README

https://github.com/apostrophecms/apostrophe-multisite/blob/master/README.md#setting-baseurl-and-naming-environments

Comment: These docs are very helpful thanks. One issue still exists in the implementation here: once I enter a baseUrl for a certain environment I have to restart the application for the change to take on the site. This strikes me as not very production worthy.

Comment: Fair, this module is not published to npm yet. In the case of multisite where `baseUrl` is controlled by the global doc, we could try to fetch it at any point in the apostrophe lifespan. But also all other permutations of Apostrophe infer `baseUrl` at app start anyway, so I don't know if I count it as a UX regression at present.

Comment: Well the problem for me is that users can create new sites at will. Their site will be unavailable until a baseUrl is set, and the entire production app restarted. Which puts me in fairly hot water. If you could point me in the right direction on where to get started addressing this in the relevant modules, I'd be happy to give it a go.

Comment: Actually, any modification of the `site` object should cause `apos` objects to be discarded for that site and reinstantiated on the next request, so it's just like the first request for that site. There could be a bug in that logic. We could prioritize this under an enterprise support arrangement if you wish.